# Lua code doesn't compile " attempt to index global 'bit' (a nil value)"

Tags: lua

how come these two lines of Lua code doesn't compile?  compiler shows error "attempt to index global 'bit' (a nil value)"

```
local rshift = bit.brshift
local lshift = bit.blshift
```

Comment: It's likely that you're using the wrong version of Lua, one that doesn't have the `bit` library.

Comment: which version has the bit library?  I tried 5.2 and 5.1 on Ubuntu.  Do i need to install the library seperately?

Comment: It is `bit32`, for 5.2

Comment: The function `bit.brshift` is implemented only in ComputerCraft.  Probably, you're trying to use this function in another Lua dialect.  In vanilla Lua 5.2 you have `bit32.rshift`, in vanilla Lua 5.3 you have operator `>>`, in LuaJIT you have `bit.rshift`